# как на кнопку положить слот из чужого класса

Tags: qt

как на кнопку положить слот из чужого класса желательно с многопоточностью.

Answer (score 1):

Если требуется просто разово выполнить метод в отдельном потоке, проще воспользоваться `QtConcurrent` примерно так:

```
QtConcurrent::run(a, &A::f);
```

UPD функция run принимает первым параметром указатель на объект, метод которого вызывается, объект `a` у вас уже объявлен как указатель, знак `&` тут лишний, исправил.

Comment: Эх хорошее решение жалко только что не работает  ошибка: no matching function for call to 'run(A**, void (A::*)())'
     QtConcurrent::run(&a, &A::f);  
        а если исправить фразу  до      QtConcurrent::run(&a, &A::f());
То будет  ошибка: cannot call member function 'void A::f()' without object
     QtConcurrent::run(&a, &A::f());
                               Куда не кинь кругом клин )))

Comment: даже если функцию из public slots в public перенести то все равно ошибки выпрыгивают (((

Comment: Исправил опечатку в ответе, смотрите upd

Comment: Сработало :3 Спасибки

Answer (score 0):

Ответ (простейший пример)  создаём проект из с UI (так быстрее). Многопоточность сделана через слот. 
Фактически мы создаём класс который общается с главным классом через механизм слотов, а сам новосозданный класс отправляем в отдельный поток.

two_classes.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator5.10 2018-05-17T09:16:05
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = two_classes
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindows.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

signals:

private slots:

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QThread * thread;
};



class Two_Class : public QObject{  // второй класс для второго потока
    Q_OBJECT
public:

public slots:
    void schet();
};


class A  : public QObject { // класс А для общения через слот с главным классом
Q_OBJECT
private:
    int i;
public slots:
    void f();
 };

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindows.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    thread = new QThread(); // инициализ класс потока

    Two_Class *two_cl = new Two_Class(); // инициализируем второй класс
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), two_cl , SLOT(schet()));
    two_cl->moveToThread(thread); // отправляем в поток
    thread->start(); // цикл обработки сообщения в потоке

    A *a = new A(); // инициализируем класс А
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), a , SLOT(f())); 
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Two_Class::schet(){
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
         for (int f=0; f<32; f++){}
        qDebug()<< "Новый поток i =" << i;
    }
}

void A::f(){
    i=3;
    qDebug()<< "i =" << i;
    for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
        qDebug()<< "Главный поток i =" << i;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]